# On the Moore-Aronszajn theorem for reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I have a question on the Moore-Aronszajn theorem regarding reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces. The theorem states that a reproducing kernel $K$ on a set $\Omega$ induces a RKHS. A kernel is defined as a function $K \colon \Omega \times \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $K(z,w) = \overline{K(w, z)}$ and has a positive semidefinite Gram-like Matrix $(K(z_i, w_j))_{i,j=1}^{n}$, for any choice of $z_i, w_j \in \Omega$ and every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. According to Wikipedia and some other sources one can find when googling the theorem, the Hilbertspace is constructed in the following way:

Consider the space $E =$ span $\{ K(w, .) \colon w \in \Omega \}$ endowed with the inner product that arises from the Gram-like matrix mentioned above. The completion of this inner product space is then the RKHS with kernel $K$.

What baffles me about this construction is that it simply does not work i.m.o. since the inner product space defined in such a manner does not carry a positive definite inner product, as required for completion. The notation on this topic also is highly confusing. A positive semidefinite kernel as defined above is called positive definite in the literature.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's any comfort, I think you're right that there's something missing in the definition. Although I'd need to think about it more, having all those finite Gram-like matrices be merely semi-definite cannot be adequate for things to work as intended. For example, the zero function would work as a kernel? Is there some typo, or something left out by accident?

Comment: well, the zero function is the kernel of the $\{ 0 \}$ I suppose. As far as any typos go, I'd invite you to google these things as I did/ look on Wikipedia for it. Maybe I really did screw something up in citing these things, so I'd be happy if someone corrected me!

Comment: Ah, well, the attempted inner product, as you've written it, is a _family_ of inner products, indexed by $n$... (and, for given $n$, the completion would be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space). A (strict) colimit of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces is never a Hilbert space. So, I ask you, what really do you intend to ask? I don't want to attempt to debate Wikipedia on such issues ... :)

Comment: ... unless, maybe, it would be helpful to you to explain how some Wikipedia entry is incorrect? Please advise?

Comment: Given two functions $f = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i K(w_i, .), g = \sum_{j=1}^{m} \beta_j K(z_j, .) \in E$ we define $(f,g) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n,m} w_i \bar{z_j} K(w_i, z_j)$. Sorry if my notation was a bit ambigious, tried to minimize the typing effort. The Wikipedia article is confusing to say at least, since it argues positive definiteness of the inner product whilst assuming positive semidefiniteness.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, but there still seems to me some imprecision... I'll look at this again tomorrow.